# Solucionar el tema de la velocidad de carga de esta pagina web

Tags: wordpress, php7, aplicación-web

Estoy trabajando en esta pagina [web](https://k-tedra.co/), cuando cargo la pagina se demora mucho  en mostrar el contenido hay alguna forma de hacerlo mas rapido?

version 7.2 de PHP.

version de Wordpress 5.3.2.

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], la pregunta parece amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: si te sirve de algo, revisa con pagespeed insights: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=es&url=https%3A%2F%2Fk-tedra.co%2F

Comment: Abre con f12 la consola del desarrollador y en la pestaña network revisa recargando la página todo lo que se solicita

Comment: Pero al ver esta información de que manera podri yo aplicarlo en este template que estoy utilizando, te agradeceria si me puedes colaborar de alguna manera para poder optimizar mas la pagina y de esta manera que la misma tenga un mejor rendimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Adicionalmente a PageSpeed Insights de @L.Ronquillo, yo uso [GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/).
En la pagina que te arroja después de hacer el análisis te da recomendaciones prácticas, te aconsejo seguirlas(en tu caso algunos recursos que no tienen expiration date)

Además proporciona una pestaña de "Waterfall" donde puedes ver específicamente cuanto tiempo lleva cada recurso, en este caso lo que más se lleva tiempo son las peticiones AJAX, si quieres optimizar tiempos puedes empezar por ahí. Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]